# Integrating $ -\frac{A}{4}\int_0^T \sin\left(\frac{2\pi t}{T} - \frac{4\pi \tau}{T}\right)d\tau $

Tags: integration, trigonometry, substitution

> Let $T$ and $A$ be constants, how do I solve the following integral?
> $$
> -\frac{A}{4}\int_0^T \sin\left(\frac{2\pi t}{T} - \frac{4\pi \tau}{T}\right)d\tau
> $$
> The solution of the integral has to be 0.

I have tried to substitute so that the term is equal to $-\frac{A}{4}\int_0^T \sin(u) \left(\frac{T\tau}{2\pi t} - \frac{T}{4\pi}\right) du$

But even if this correct, then I would have to substitute again, so this cannot be the right way.

Comment: I would recommend starting with angle sum identity for $sin$.

Comment: Hint: $\dfrac{2\pi\tau}T$ describes an entire period of the sinus, therefore ...

Comment: @zwim If $\tau=1.5$ and $T=1$ then it wouldn't be an entire period of the sinus, or am I on the wrong path here? Also, you probably meant $t$ instead of $\tau$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First notice that $\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(u)du=0\quad$ (same if it was cosinus under the integral).

Shifting the variable doesn't change the value:

$\require{cancel}\displaystyle\begin{align}\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(u+\varphi)du
&=\int_{\varphi}^{2\pi+\varphi}\sin(u)du\\
&=\int_{\varphi}^{0}\sin(u)du+\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin(u)du+\int_{2\pi}^{2\pi+\varphi}\sin(u)du\\
&=-\cancel{\int_0^{\varphi}\sin(u)du}+\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin(u)du+\cancel{\int_{0}^{\varphi}\underbrace{\sin(u+2\pi)}_{\sin(u)}du}\\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin(u)du\end{align}$

And this stays the same if you take the integral over an integer number of periods (I let it as an exercise for you):

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin(nu+\phi)du=0\quad n\in\mathbb Z^*$$

In the present case $\varphi=\dfrac{2\pi t}T$ is a constant.

And for $\tau\in[0,T]$ then $\dfrac{4\pi\tau}{T}\in[0,4\pi]$ covers $n=2$ times the
period.

Therefore your integral is zero without having to do any calculation!

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{split}
\frac{A}{4}\int_0^T \sin\left( \frac{4\pi}{T}\left(\tau -\frac{t}{2}\right)\right)\, \mathrm{d}\tau 
 &\overset{u = \frac{4\pi}{T}\left(\tau -\frac{t}{2}\right)}{=}
  \frac{AT}{16\pi} \int_{-\frac{2t\pi}{T}}^{\frac{4\pi}{T}\left(T-\frac{t}{2}\right)}\sin(u) \,\mathrm{d}u \\
 &= \frac{AT}{16\pi}  \cos(u)\Bigg\vert_{u = {\frac{4\pi}{T}\left(T-\frac{t}{2}\right)}}^{u=-\frac{2t\pi}{T}}
\end{split}
$$

Comment: The problem is that the solution has to be 0.

Answer (score 2):

Let
$x =\frac{2 \pi t}{T}-\frac{4 \pi \tau}{T} \textrm{ then } d x =-\frac{4 \pi}{T} d \tau $ and
$$
\begin{aligned}
-\frac{A}{4}\int_0^T \sin\left(\frac{2\pi t}{T} - \frac{4\pi \tau}{T}\right)d\tau &=-\frac{A}{4} \int_{\frac{2 \pi t}{T}}^{\frac{2 \pi t}{T} -4\pi} \sin x \left(-\frac{4 \pi}{T} d \tau\right) \\
&=-\frac{A \pi}{T}\left[\cos x\right]_{\frac{2 \pi t}{T}}^{\frac{2 \pi t}{T}-4 \pi} \\
&=-\frac{A \pi}{T}\left[\cos \left(\frac{2 \pi t}{T}-4 \pi\right)-\cos \frac{2 \pi t}{T}\right] \\
&=-\frac{A \pi}{T}\left(\cos \frac{2 \pi t}{T}-\cos \frac{2 \pi t}{T}\right) \\
&=0
\end{aligned}
$$
Wish it helps.